# Django cms hide menu item when the page is empty

Tags: python, django-cms

I have created a menu using django cms, there is a menu item named 'News'. There is a page linked to this menu item News, when there is no article in it, this menu item has to hide from the menu otherwise it has to visible. The problem is when all the articles are deleted in the News page the menu item still appears in the menu until or unless the server is not restarted. Can any one help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the django cms caching documents? There is a discussion about the caching in the django cms. Have a look at [this](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/caching.html)

There is also an option to use the cache plugin.

Also check this note in the documentation;

> If you disable a plugin cache be sure to restart the server and clear the cache afterwards.